# bundler installed gems not persisting in fig/docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am trying to use fig and docker to set up a local development environment for an existing rails app.

In the build process, I clearly see bundler installing the app's gems, but when I try to start the container with `fig up` or even reopen it with the /bin/bash command, the gems are not visible.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# REPOS
RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js
RUN apt-get -y update

#INSTALL
RUN apt-get install -y -q build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison pkg-config libpq-dev make wget unzip git vim nano nodejs gawk libgdbm-dev libffi-dev

#RUBY
RUN mkdir -p /download 
WORKDIR download
RUN wget http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby-2.1.2.tar.gz
RUN tar xvfz ruby-2.1.2.tar.gz

WORKDIR /download/ruby-2.1.2

RUN ./configure 
RUN make
RUN make install
RUN gem update --system
RUN gem install bundler
RUN mkdir /rent
WORKDIR /rent
ADD Gemfile /rent/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /rent/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install --deployment
```

And here is the fig.yml file:

```
web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000
  volumes:
    - .:/rent
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
```

Running `fig build` clearly shows the app's gems being installed.
Running `fig up` fails with the message

> bundler: command not found: rails

If I run `fig run web /bin/bash` and check the contents of

> /local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems

it only has bundler, rdoc, rake and a few others installed.

If I navigate to the app's directory and run the `bundle` command, it will install the app's gems and I can see that they are installed in the directory above. I can even start the app with `rails server`.

Why aren't the bundled gems being persisted in the image(container?).

I ran the rails tutuorial from the fig website and didn't have this problem.

Thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, I see the same problem running docker build .

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem was caused by using the `--deployment` flag with `bundle install`.

This flag's main effect is to deploy the gems to the vendor/bundle/ directory instead of the normal gem location.  I checked and the gems were there, so I'm not sure why ruby couldn't find them.

Anyways, removing `--deployment` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [fig](https://github.com/docker/fig) and mounted volumes, I found a solution which allows updates to the mounted files in development (like Gemfile.lock when you do `fig run web bundle install`) while still keeping container caching behavior.

See this for the full thing: https://gist.github.com/fotinakis/04077671bec4edf77c08

It's slightly convoluted, but basically you always install bundler and the gems as the non-root application user:

```
# Add 'web' user which will run the application.
RUN adduser web --home /home/web --shell /bin/bash --disabled-password --gecos ""

# Add directory where all application code will live and own it by the web user.
RUN mkdir /app
RUN chown -R web:web /app

# Install gems separately here to take advantage of container caching of `bundle install`.
# Also, ensure that gems are installed as the web user and not system-wide so that we can run
# `fig web bundle install` and the web user will have permissions to update the shared Gemfile.lock.
ADD Gemfile /app/
ADD Gemfile.lock /app/
RUN chown -R web:web /app
USER web
ENV HOME /home/web
ENV PATH $PATH:/home/web/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin
ENV GEM_HOME /home/web/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
ENV GEM_PATH $GEM_HOME
RUN gem install --user-install bundler
WORKDIR /app/
RUN bundle install
USER root

# Add the whole application source to the image and own it all by web:web.
# Note: this is overwritten in development because fig mounts a shared volume at /app.
ADD . /app/
RUN chown -R web:web /app
```

Running this will now work and update your local Gemfile.lock:

```
$ fig run web bundle install
```